# Find links that buttons redirect to

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have a series of SSRN article links. For all of them I want to do this:
Example for one of the articles:

Article Link:
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3551767
There is a button called "Open PDF in browser". I want to automatically retrieve the link that the button redirects to. If you do this manually, you will see that if you click it it will take you [here](https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=439105103119121121090083116085026123000005036021011004064070031091104012064103095075106063016032058001000022088078082118077006016035075003021000072095031003079122116018077095113095098114102118116016126092115089029005095103071073068105094126004101013096&EXT=pdf). How can I do this in code? Is Selenium the best choice?

Comment: do you want to go to the link or get the link

Comment: @AomineDaici I just want to get the link of the PDF